# Laravel pagination reduce the number of links

Tags: laravel, pagination

For now my Laravel pagination shows [< 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8...30,31 >](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yzo8I.png), but I want this to become [< 1,2,3,4,5...30,31 >](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nd9sF.png). How can I perform the change? I have reviewed a lot of instructions on different topics, but the changes do not propagate on my website.

I have managed to get the < 1,2,3,4,5...30,31 > by changing the protected function getUrlSlider($onEachSide) { $window = $onEachSide * 1; (this was * 2 before) However now, I am facing again a 15 links issue when I am moving into the middle pages. ‹ 1 2 ... 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 ... 35 36 › with 8 as current page, so I will need for this to show something like ‹ 1 2 ... 7 8 9 ... 35 36 ›

I have added the code here:

```
/**
 * The paginator implementation.
 *
 * @var \Illuminate\Contracts\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator
 */
protected $paginator;

/**
 * Create a new URL window instance.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator  $paginator
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct(PaginatorContract $paginator)
{
    $this->paginator = $paginator;
}

/**
 * Create a new URL window instance.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator  $paginator
 * @return array
 */
public static function make(PaginatorContract $paginator)
{
    return (new static($paginator))->get();
}

/**
 * Get the window of URLs to be shown.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function get()
{
    $onEachSide = $this->paginator->onEachSide;

    if ($this->paginator->lastPage() < ($onEachSide * 1) + 3) {
        return $this->getSmallSlider();
    }

    return $this->getUrlSlider($onEachSide);
}

/**
 * Get the slider of URLs there are not enough pages to slide.
 *
 * @return array
 */
protected function getSmallSlider()
{
    return [
        'first'  => $this->paginator->getUrlRange(1, $this->lastPage()),
        'slider' => null,
        'last'   => null,
    ];
}

/**
 * Create a URL slider links.
 *
 * @param  int  $onEachSide
 * @return array
 */
protected function getUrlSlider($onEachSide)
{
    $window = $onEachSide * 1;

    if (! $this->hasPages()) {
        return ['first' => null, 'slider' => null, 'last' => null];
    }

    // If the current page is very close to the beginning of the page range, we will
    // just render the beginning of the page range, followed by the last 2 of the
    // links in this list, since we will not have room to create a full slider.
    if ($this->currentPage() <= $window) {
        return $this->getSliderTooCloseToBeginning($window);
    }

    // If the current page is close to the ending of the page range we will just get
    // this first couple pages, followed by a larger window of these ending pages
    // since we're too close to the end of the list to create a full on slider.
    elseif ($this->currentPage() > ($this->lastPage() - $window)) {
        return $this->getSliderTooCloseToEnding($window);
    }

    // If we have enough room on both sides of the current page to build a slider we
    // will surround it with both the beginning and ending caps, with this window
    // of pages in the middle providing a Google style sliding paginator setup.
    return $this->getFullSlider($onEachSide);
}

/**
 * Get the slider of URLs when too close to beginning of window.
 *
 * @param  int  $window
 * @return array
 */
protected function getSliderTooCloseToBeginning($window)
{
    return [
        'first' => $this->paginator->getUrlRange(1, $window + 2),
        'slider' => null,
        'last' => $this->getFinish(),
    ];
}

/**
 * Get the slider of URLs when too close to ending of window.
 *
 * @param  int  $window
 * @return array
 */
protected function getSliderTooCloseToEnding($window)
{
    $last = $this->paginator->getUrlRange(
        $this->lastPage() - ($window + 2),
        $this->lastPage()
    );

    return [
        'first' => $this->getStart(),
        'slider' => null,
        'last' => $last,
    ];
}

/**
 * Get the slider of URLs when a full slider can be made.
 *
 * @param  int  $onEachSide
 * @return array
 */
protected function getFullSlider($onEachSide)
{
    return [
        'first'  => $this->getStart(),
        'slider' => $this->getAdjacentUrlRange($onEachSide),
        'last'   => $this->getFinish(),
    ];
}

/**
 * Get the page range for the current page window.
 *
 * @param  int  $onEachSide
 * @return array
 */
public function getAdjacentUrlRange($onEachSide)
{
    return $this->paginator->getUrlRange(
        $this->currentPage() - $onEachSide,
        $this->currentPage() + $onEachSide
    );
}

/**
 * Get the starting URLs of a pagination slider.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function getStart()
{
    return $this->paginator->getUrlRange(1, 2);
}

/**
 * Get the ending URLs of a pagination slider.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function getFinish()
{
    return $this->paginator->getUrlRange(
        $this->lastPage() - 1,
        $this->lastPage()
    );
}

/**
 * Determine if the underlying paginator being presented has pages to show.
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function hasPages()
{
    return $this->paginator->lastPage() > 1;
}

/**
 * Get the current page from the paginator.
 *
 * @return int
 */
protected function currentPage()
{
    return $this->paginator->currentPage();
}

/**
 * Get the last page from the paginator.
 *
 * @return int
 */
protected function lastPage()
{
    return $this->paginator->lastPage();
}
```

}

Comment: Show the code you're using and what you've tried. You might be closer than you think, but it's impossible for us to tell unless you post your attempts.

Comment: I have managed to get the < 1,2,3,4,5...30,31 > by changing the protected function 

getUrlSlider($onEachSide)
{
    $window = $onEachSide * 1; (this was * 2 before)

However now, I am facing again a 15  links issue when I am moving into the middle pages. ‹ 1 2 ... 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 ... 35 36 › with 8 as current page, so I will need for this to show something like ‹ 1 2 ...   7 8 9   ... 35 36 ›

Answer (score 1):

try like this:

```
Model::paginate(10)->onEachSide(5);
```

Comment: I have managed to get the < 1,2,3,4,5...30,31 > by changing the protected function getUrlSlider($onEachSide) { $window = $onEachSide * 1; (this was * 2 before) However now, I am facing again a 15 links issue when I am moving into the middle pages. ‹ 1 2 ... 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 ... 35 36 › with 8 as current page, so I will need for this to show something like ‹ 1 2 ... 7 8 9 ... 35 36 ›